# How can an admin of a Facebook group automatically reject membership requests without rule acceptance?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

You're an admin of a large Facebook group with a list of rules. To become a group member, a general Facebook user has to tick the box that he/she accepts the rules; no other questions are asked. How can you set up admin assist (or any other tool) such that the users that have not ticked rule acceptance are automatically rejected and temporarily blocked (say, for a month) from becoming a member (with a notice on what they've done wrong)?

Background: Your group receives too much attention, and so far you couldn't find any co-admin or moderator who would do proper daily cleanup of posts and members. You wish to automate the handling of the applications for membership.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please [edit] your question to be specific to a problem that you're facing rather than hypotheticals.  See [ask] for more info.

Comment: @BlindSpots As for admin assist: had I found the info in the documentation, I wouldn't have asked here.

Comment: Since [Admin Assist documentation](https://www.facebook.com/help/436275657385753) includes no reference to any of the requested functions ([Q1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172073), [Q2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172072), [Q3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172075)).  ***"any other tool"*** requests should posted to [softwarerecs.se].  If you want a code/API-based solution then [so] might be better.  To have this question migrated to another site, [edit] it ***after*** reviewing the target site's guidelines, then leave a comment or mod flag requesting migration.

Comment: Please review my comments as well as [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and [What if I disagree with the closure of a question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) to better understand your options.